# Insert a new field into an existing collection (many documents) in MongoDB using C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

How can I insert a new field into a MongoDB collection using the C# `Update` API?

What I am trying to do: I have a `HomePhoneId` field that I need to insert into every document in my `People` collection.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following code should work:

```
collection.Update(Query.Null, Update.Set("HomePhoneId", "some value"), UpdateFlags.Multi)
```

Btw, [here is](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/getting_started/quick_tour/) you can look into driver documentation.

Comment: Thanks Andrew.Any ideas how to set a value in a list within the collection.

Comment: Any ideas on inserting into an array or list property within a document?

Comment: @Deefa: You may looking for [positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator)?

Answer (score 4):

Following code should work:

```
        var filterDefinition = Builders<Models.Doctor>.Filter.Where(w => w.Name!=null);
        var updateDefinition = Builders<Models.Doctor>.Update
            .Set(d => d.IsApproved, value);
        _doctorRepository.Collection.UpdateMany(filterDefinition, updateDefinition);
```